# Understanding MVVM Cross Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

am trying to use MVVM Cross with Xamarin and found it very interesting.

Following [Adding packages](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/getting-started/mvvmcross-packages#mvvmcross-packages) i tried adding the listed "MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging" Nuget to PCL where am getting Errors.

```
Error: but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework(Profile 111). For more 
information, contact the package author.
```

Please help understanding the dilemma in installing MVVM Cross packages across Projects(PCL,Droid and IOS) and about PCL Profiling WRT MVVMCross,as existing documentation is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can't add an Android package to a PCL library. PCL is just compatible with other PCL libraries.

Also i would suggest using the MvvmCross support packages instead of FullFragging as they are more maintained by Google.